# Prevent scrolling anchor link for touch devices only

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a the following anchor link.

```
<a href="#location">Link 1</a>
```

For desktop it shouldscroll down the page to the id '#location', this is working but then if the html has the touch class from Modenizr then it should open the #mobileClientList div. At present on iPad its running both functions, scrolling down the page and then opening the div.

#### JS

```
$('#clientMenuButton').click(function(e) {
  if ($('html.touch').length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mobileClientList').fadeToggle('slow');
  } else {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, "href")).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  }
});
```

#### Coffee Script

```
$('#clientMenuButton').click (e) ->
  if $('html.touch').length > 0
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#mobileClientList').fadeToggle 'slow'
    return
  else
    $("html, body").animate
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, "href")).offset().top
   , 500
   false
```